# There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

This is probably not the best way to be doing this but it's the best I know how to do with c#. I'm trying to create a dictionary and then convert it to json later. Right now I"m just trying to get the dictionary to match what I want in the json format later. Here is what I have so far:

```
`Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, List<List<Decimal>>>> testDict = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, List<List<Decimal>>>>() {
    new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "test", "test" }
    }
};`
```

This is giving me the following error:

> There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter

I don't know what could be causing this and any help would be great, thanks!

Here is the json structure I'm trying to replicate:

```
[
  {
    "target": "1",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        67.0,
        1491609600.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "2",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        54.0,
        1491091200.0
      ],
      [
        65.0,
        1491177600.0
      ],
      [
        69.0,
        1491609600.0
      ],
      [
        65.0,
        1491696000.0
      ],
      [
        54.0,
        1491868800.0
      ],
      [
        63.0,
        1491955200.0
      ],
      [
        64.0,
        1492214400.0
      ],
      [
        57.0,
        1492732800.0
      ],
      [
        72.0,
        1492819200.0
      ],
      [
        50.0,
        1493337600.0
      ],
      [
        63.0,
        1493424000.0
      ]
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the value in your initializer.  You've specified a key (`new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "test", "test" }}`, but you're missing the `, value` part of the initializer.  To fix the compilation problem, try this: `Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, List<List<Decimal>>>> testDict = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, List<List<Decimal>>>>() {
   { new Dictionary<string, string> { { "test", "test" } }, new Dictionary<string, List<List<decimal>>>() }
  };`

Comment: 100% sure that structure is totally wrong... If you post the JSON structure you need maybe someone can post the real classes you need.

Comment: @Gusman Take a look at my updated question :)

Comment: That looks like it should be a `List<SomeType>` where  `SomeType` is a custom class with `Target` and `DataPoints` properties... you really don't want the type that you're declaring at the moment.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string>` can't be a key for dictionary as it does not have meaningful hashcode/equals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not the answer to your question, but it will help, is the correct structure for your JSON:

```
public class TargetClass
{
    public string target{ get; set; }
    public List<double[]> datapoints{ get; set; }
}
```

That's the base class. If you want to deserialize what you have in JSON you will do something like this (assuming you are using Newtonsoft Json, else change to the library you use):

```
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TargetClass[]>(theString);
```

And to serialize you would create something like this:

```
var items = new List<TargetClass>();

var target = new TargetClass{ target = "1", datapoints = new List<double[]>{ new double[]{ 67.0, 1491609600.0 } };

items.Add(target);

var ser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using anonymous types you can create complex object hierarchies almost as easy as writing plain JSON:

```
var obj = new[] {
    new {
        target = "1",
        datapoints = new [] {
            new [] {
                67.0,
                1491609600.0
            }
        }
    },
    new {
        target = "2",
        datapoints = new [] {
            new [] {
                54.0,
                1491091200.0
            },
            new [] {
                65.0,
                1491177600.0
            },
        }
    }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jk8gho

---

If subcollections in this object are a subject to expansion, these collections should better be explicitly defined as `List<dynamic>`. Strictly speaking this `dynamic` is not necessary and explicit types may be used instead, but using `dynamic` simplifies the definition.

```
var obj = new List<dynamic> {
    new {
        target = "1",
        datapoints = new List<dynamic> {
            new [] {
                67.0,
                1491609600.0
            }
        }
    },
    new {
        target = "2",
        datapoints = new List<dynamic> {
            new [] {
                54.0,
                1491091200.0
            },
            new [] {
                65.0,
                1491177600.0
            },
        }
    }
};

var target2 = obj.Where(t => t.target == "2").Single();
target2.datapoints.Add(new [] {
    64.0,
    1492214400.0
});
target2.datapoints.Add(new[] {
    57.0,
    1492732800.0
});

var target3 = new {
    target = "3",
    datapoints = new List<dynamic> { }
};
target3.datapoints.Add(new[] {
    72.0,
    1492819200.0
});
obj.Add(target3);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/d4ZUH8

Comment: How would that save the problem?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: the main issue OP expresses is handling complex object definition, which should be mapped to a JSON of certain structure. With the suggested approach this mapping is straightforward.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov I agree, this is very straight forward and I like that. Is there a way I can add more target objects to it while I'm looping around my data?

Comment: The structure you posted would not allow you to de-serialize the object, not even reference it from another method.

Comment: @JoeScotto: Yes, this is possible but you would have to change `new []` to `new List<dynamic>` for the collection you intend to expand. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: We may deserialize it using `DeserializeAnonymousType` (let alone defining POCOs should we really want to.) As of passing to other methods, we may use `dynamic` for anonymous type instances. See demo for both: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kttehz